# I can't understand why my code is printing an output of -1? The answer is 4

Tags: java, string

I can't understand why my code is printing an output of -1? It should print 4 because that’s how many times, minimum, A repeats for B to be a substring.

MGiven two strings A and B, find the minimum number of times A has to be repeated such that B is a substring of it. If no such solution, return -1.
For example, with A = "abcd" and B = "cdabcdab".
Return 3, because by repeating A three times (“abcdabcdabcd”), B is a substring of it; and B is not a substring of A repeated two times ("abcdabcd").
Note:
The length of A and B will be between 1 and 10000.

My input for string A is: "abc"
My input for string B is: "cabcabca"
My output is : -1
The output should be : 4

```
class Solution {
    public int repeatedStringMatch(String A, String B) {


        String result = A;
        int count = 1;

        if(A.contains(B)) {
        return 1;
        }


        if(A.length() == 1 && B.length() == 1) {
            if(!A.equals(B)) {
                return -1;
            } else {
            return 1;
            }  
        } else {
            while(!result.contains(B)) {
                if(result.length() > B.length()) {
                    result += A;
                    count++;

                    if(A.contains(B)) {
                        return count;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }  

                result += A;
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Expected : 4
Output: -1

Comment: Time to debug ...

Comment: when will `A.contains(B)` be `true`? (for `-1` not being returned)

Comment: another hint... the first time through the debug you will see the issue. also instead of returning 1 in a bunch of places you can remove that and just return count. also i don't see `1000` used anywhere in your code how will it know when to stop

Comment: You should not return -1 in the if inside the while loop. This is a logical error. The while loop iterates only one time because it contains an "if" that returns always (with "count" or "-1")

Comment: @second ??? Title: "*is printing an output of -1?*" and text:  "*My output is : -1*"

Comment: @second  two times `-1` versus one `1`....

Comment: @mavriksc I tried to use 1000. It timed out.

Comment: @Carlos: Yeah, I missed the not in the while loop. I agree with you the output should be -1. Still leaves the typo below the example.

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger A will be true when it’s long enough that B can be a sub string of it

Comment: is "abc" (A) long enough so that "cabcabca" (B) is a substring of it? since `A.contains(B)` is `false` the `if` is going to the `else` branch and executing `return -1` ==> that is why you are getting a `-1`

Comment: you are commenting on the wrong place... and the length of A is not changing, the code is **not** adding A to itself, it is being added to `result` (hint to solution!)

Comment: @Carlos no that’s why I add A to itself until it’s either longer or can contain B

Comment: Oh sheesh. I see. Thank you @Carlos

Answer (score 0):

@Macanga is close but the problem is here

```
} else {
        while(!result.contains(B)) {
            if(result.length() > B.length()) {
                result += A;
                count++;

                if(A.contains(B)) {// here vvv
                    return count;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }                  //^^^^^^^^
            }  

            result += A;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
```

Chances are it doesn't contain the other string so boom -1. 
also this `if(A.length() == 1 && B.length() == 1) {`doesn't do anything meaning full
basically a cannot contain b until it is longer than b so  you need to keep adding multiples until you get to that length before even checking for the content. then while the multiples lenght is less than 1000 keep going. there is probably some proof that you only need to go to 2x the length of B max but that is a different issue.

Comment: if you want to check initial condition you can just compare their length to each other, both of them being length 1 means nothing more than them being the same length, as far as this problem is concerned.

Comment: That makes sense. But it does contain the string with its repeated four times. That’s why when the A length is bigger, I add string A to itself again. Then check and see if that did it, or not , return -1

Comment: @learning do you see why it is happening the very first time? it doesn't get to count=4 only if the string is contained in the first loop will it return a correct answer. are you able to debug and step through it running? i think that will help you a lot.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger the ultimate goal for us is to be efficient. if it's purpose is faulty inconplete or unclear. while also being covered by already present and correct code.  my statement here is draw attention to intention. "does this code do what you think it does" "if we are adding this extra check to quit out early is it actually saving time?" " is this already covered by things checked later?"

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing

```
 if(A.contains(B)) {
       return count;
     } else {
        return -1;
   }
```

Do this:

```
if(result.contains(B)) {
           return count;
         } else {
            return -1;
       }
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nhdqL2bs/33/